# How to send data/variable from one method to another in the same controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 functions/methods in the same controller in CodeIgniter like this:

```
public function _get_page_settings() {
    $page_settings = $this->page_model->get_page_settings();
    $data['ps'] = $page_settings;
}

public function registration() {
    $this->_get_page_settings();
    $this->load->view('page_registration', $data);
}
```

The first method **_get_page_settings()** grabs some stuff from db and store it in a variable ps inside data array.

I want to use this method in many other methods inside this controller.

So, how to send data correctly to **registration()** because this code above is not working OK. It throw this error in my view:
Message: Undefined variable: data on line 70 which is this line:
**$this->load->view('page_registration', $data);**

EDIT: **SOLVED!**

I have finally figured it out. You can do it like this:

```
public function _get_page_settings() {
    $data['ps'] = $this->page_model->get_page_settings();
    $this->ps = $data['ps'];
}

public function registration() {
    $this->_get_page_settings();
    $this->load->view('page_registration', $this->ps);
}
```

And to output it in the view e.g.:

```
<?php echo $this->ps->page_name; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data` simply has different visibility scope, this is not CodeIgniter specific. You can solve this in two ways:

- Make `$data` a class property (`$this->data`)
- Make `_get_page_settings()` to return `$data` and assign it to a variable when calling it.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? ;)